# Configuring res srcDirs for androidTest sourceSet

Tags: java, android, android-testing, build.gradle

I'd like to include resources to be compiled only for testing.

I have the following in my app module build.gradle file:

```
android {

    ...

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/res']
        }
    }
}
```

The java srcDirs path is correct, yet if I try to get a resource from the res directory in androidTest, the resource can't be found.

How can I have resources in the androidTest directory that are only included for tests?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out you don't need to change anything from the default build.gradle file.

The trick is that the auto-generated `R.java` file is different for resources in `androidTest`.

If the import statement for `R` somewhere in your main source set looks like:

```
import com.mycompany.myappname.R;
```

the import statement for `R` in a test file should look like:

```
import com.mycompany.myappname.test.R;
```

Comment: Works for me too, but in InstrumentationTestCase only. If using this in an AndroidTestCase, the resource ID's aren't the same and I got a random PNG image instead of the XML file I requested.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a build type where you've set the `applicationIdSuffix`, your `src/androidTest/res` resources are going to be at `<applicationId><applicationIdSuffix>.test.R` !!!!! **VERY IMPORTANT**!!!

i.e.

```
applicationId "com.example.my.app"

buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

have some resources in `src/androidTest/res`? They're NOT at `com.example.my.app.test`! If you're running the debug build, they're at `com.example.my.app.debug.test.R` !!!!

Comment: What makes you think OP set an **applicationIdSuffix**?