# Espresso: How to use R.string resources of androidTest folder

Tags: android, testing, android-resources, android-testing, android-espresso

I want to put data in xml file of androidTest/res/values/string.xml folder. I have created the file say test.xml with below contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="test">hello</string>
</resources>
```

When i am trying to access the field test via R.string.test. It is not accessible and says "cannot resolve symbol test". Can someone please advice me here.

Comment: you dont need define strings in test folder , define them in main projects resource file

Comment: @sabersafavi , actually we have credit card etc information that we want to store and use them in espresso tests. As its critical information, we neither want it to be stored in the main project file nor want to delete it every time when we build a release build apk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring res srcDirs for androidTest sourceSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663539/configuring-res-srcdirs-for-androidtest-sourceset)

Comment: @MyDogTom, i already tried the solution provided in the link and it does not work. I can not locate the resources.

Comment: @Bingo I tested the provided solution and it works. You need to create a file `strings.xml` under `src/androidTest/res/values` and import `com.yourpackage.test.R` into your test.

Comment: The trick here is the right import, because by default AS imports `com.yourpackage.test.R` instead of `com.yourpackage.test.R`. So you need to fix it manually.

Comment: @MyDogTom, i have tried it. I can only see one default parameter that can be imported.  com.android.todo.test.R.string.app_name i can not access any newly added parameter

Comment: @Bingo please provide more information about your setup, your test etc. Ideally a simple project which will illustrate this strange behavior.

Comment: @MyDogTom Thanks, I got it working now. The missing part was including it in the gradle file                                                                                                  sourceSets { debug { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/test/res', 'src/androidTest/res', 'src/debug/res'] } }

Comment: @Bingo Can you help me to get it run, I have similar configuration in my application but when I tried to access string resource using getTargetContext.getString(R.string.product_name) or using mAcitivityRule.getActivity.getString(R.string.product_name) getting some random value which is even not used anywhere in resource file. String output:  "res/drawable-v21/abc_action_bar_item_background_material.xml"

Comment: @user3400729 `getTargetContext()` will read the values from the app's APK; I think the point with the `androidTest` folder is that the instrumentation tests are a different APK so you need to use `getContext()` for reading resources from that.

Answer (score 24):

This is how you do it:

`import com.my.example.test.R;`

```
Resources resources = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getResources();
String terms = resources.getString(R.string.test);
```

Answer (score 10):

`androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry` is deprecated use `androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider`

```
val targetContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
val test: String =  targetContext.resources.getString(R.string.test)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a longstanding Android library project in which I had renamed my sources' package at some point from `a.b.c.d` to `a.b.c` but I had forgot to change the `package` value in my library's `AndroidManifest.xml` file likewise. This led to some confusion when I added a `res/values/strings.xml` file to my library's `androidTest` folder but I was unable to see an `a.b.c.test.R` object in my test classes.

The solution for me was to rename the `package` value in my library's `AndroidManifest.xml` file to match my sources' package (i.e. `a.b.c`). I am now able to see an `a.b.c.test.R` object in my test classes and I am able to access the string resources defined in `androidTest/res/values/strings.xml` via the `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.getString(resId:)` method.